# Question on limits and integration

Tags: integration, limits

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Then the $\lim_{n\to ∞}\int_{0}^{1}nx^nf(x)$ is equal to ?

What I did: I tried for $f(x)=x$ and on computing the integral and the limit I got the answer = $1 \implies f(1)$[ according to the options]. However, I do not know if this is a valid way to generalize the answer for all functions continuous on $[0,1]$.

Can anyone please help me solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\int_0^{1} nx^{n} [f(x)-f(1)]dx=\int_0^{r} nx^{n} [f(x)-f(1)]dx+\int_r^{1} nx^{n} [f(x)-f(1)]dx$. Use continuity of $f$ at $1$ to make the second term small by choosing $r$ close enough to $1$. Then use the fact that $|f(x)-f(1)|$ is bounded and $\int_0^{r} nx^{n} dx=\frac {nr^{n+1}} {n+1} \to 0$ to show that $\int_0^{1} nx^{n} [f(x)-f(1)]dx \to 0$. Can you finish the proof now?

Comment: @adityabhatt Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thank you, I finished the proof with the help of your hint. I have a doubt though: $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1] \implies f(x)$ is bounded and hence $|f(x) - f(1)|$ is bounded - Is this line of reasoning correct?

Comment: Then, this same reasoning can also be used if we replace $f(1)$ by $f(0)$. But $f(0)$ is not the correct answer

Comment: can you explain why we cannot have $f(0)$ instead of $f(1)$ in your answer to this question?

Comment: @adityabhatt If you conisder $f(x)-f(0)$ instead of $f(x)-f(1)$  you will have to handle the behavior of $nx^{n}$ near $1$. $nx^{n} \to 0$ for each $x<1$ but tends to $\infty$ when $x=1$ and this causes problems with the proof.